# how to retrieve value from <input> using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

[Please help me solve this problem that i have been trying to solve for hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbbf9.png)

Comment: Please read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: There are plenty of stuff to read and watch...Code once think twice !

Answer (score 0):

you should have a `function` to handle the `onChange` `value` of your `input field` like below.

this is the method to handle the `onChange` of your `text input`

```
 handleOnChange(event){
       console.log('the input text is :', event.target.value);
       this.setState({
           //set the value for what you want here
       });

   }
```

this is how your `input` field should looks like.

```
render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
       <input type="text" onChange={(event)this.handleOnChange(event)} />
      </div>
    );
}
```

hope this will help to you.